# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to read property set by CLLocation newLocation

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, cllocationmanager, cllocation

So I have a model object, which is a named 'location' which has a set of properties  on. One of which is '**distanceFromUserLocation**'. Obviously, to know this it needs to know the user's location, so in the model object I am calculating the user's current location.

This also sets a **CLLocation** property on this model every time on the didUpdateToLocation method.

I also have an **initWithDictionary** method on the model which sets all the values for properties on the location model.

code below for my model:

```
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize entryLocation = _entryLocation;
@synthesize address = _address;
@synthesize contactNumber = _contactNumber;
@synthesize distanceFromUserLocation = _distanceFromUserLocation;
@synthesize itemDescription = _itemDescription;
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;
@synthesize userLocation = _userLocation;


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation        *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation != nil) {
        self.userLocation = newLocation;
        NSLog(@"lat: %@ lon: %@ ", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f",   newLocation.coordinate.latitude], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
    }

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dictionary
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.name = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Name"];
        self.address = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Address"];
        self.contactNumber = [dictionary valueForKey:@"ContactNumber"];
        self.itemDescription = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Description"];
        double lat = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
        double lon = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
        self.entryLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
        self.distanceFromUserLocation = [self.userLocation distanceFromLocation:self.entryLocation];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The problem I have, is that in the **didUpdateToLocation**, I am setting the '**self.currentLocation**' property to the value of **newLocation**. I then log the lat and the long to make sure i actually have a value, which I do.

However, when i then initialize an instance of the 'Location' model from my controller class and then log the value for currentLocation on that model object:

```
NSLog(@"%@", location.currentLocation);
```

I get (null) in the log.

If i try:

```
NSLog(@%@", location.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
```

I get a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error.

I am successfully getting the current location in the didUpdateToLocation and loggint it, but then why when I set my currentLocation property to the value of newLocation does it not get retained?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Use `%f` in your `NSLog` call, may help.

Comment: Just tried, and instead of (nill), now i get 0.0000 instead :( thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error was down to what joost and JBat100 suggested. Just down to using %@ instead of %f. I did however figure out why I couldn't ever get the user location value out of the property on the controller. The methods are called asynchronously and the forRowAtIndexPath method was rendering the table cells BEFORE user location could ever be found, so the pointer to userlocation was pointing to nothing when it was called.

I solved it by adding a view with an activity indicator which finds the user location, saves it to a property and THEN pushes the view with the table in onto the screen, setting it's userlocation property that way so that the property is never empty :)

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
location.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
```

Is of type CLLocationDegrees which defined as

```
typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```

You can only use %@ with class instances that inherit from NSObject (generally speaking). You should be printing out a double like this:

```
NSLog(@"%f", location.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
```

When you use the accessor

```
self.userLocation = newLocation;
```

the value is retained if the property is specified as retain.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately when I do that, instead of getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, I just get 0 in the log, and stil (nil) when i try and log the whole currentLocation object.

Comment: When you say "However, when i then initialize an instance of the 'Location' model from my controller class", do you mean you initialize a new instance of CLLocation, or you have defined a Location class yourself? If so you could have the currentLocation as a static class variable so that it persists. But remember to check the timestamp when you get a location (the system can give you an old location which you should ignore).

Comment: I have defined a location class myself, with a set of properties :) the code above is from the location class.

Comment: When you create a new instance of a class you should expect its ivars to be nil by default (in the case of NSObject subclasses), unless they are initiated in the constructor. There is no reason for the currentLocation of a new instance to be set to another instance's currentLocation. Unless you make it a static variable and use a static accessor to get to it.

Comment: ah right, but i was under the impression that what Im doing above sets the property of currentLocation every time an instance of the class is created? the initWithDictionary sets most of the values and calls the startUpdatingLocation on the locationManager property and then sets the currentLocation of that instance? Or have I got it completely back to front? thanks for your help! :)

Comment: It will start updating the location when the class instance is created, however the currentLocation will not be updated until the -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation: (CLLocation *)oldLocation callback is called. This is done asynchronously and can take a long time (sometimes fail to get called completely). In which case you would get the - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error callback.

Comment: but currentLocation is ALWAYS null, regardless of when its called, but newLocation ALWAYS returns a correct value. Why then, is setting currentLocation = newLocation never setting currentLocation to a value?

Answer (score 0):

The values sent to `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` (I hope you are using that, and not the less dependable `MKMapView` delegate method) aren't very reliable.  In theory, you should get a successive selection of gradually more accurate values.  However, often a nil value is sent, as you have noticed and are checking for in your code; but a coordinate of `0.0,0.0` is also often sent, and you should check for and ignore that.  It is also a good idea to check the `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` properties for negative values and reject those `CLLocation`s also.

Comment: well when the apps starts up, instances of my location model object are created, and one of the properties on the location model is 'distanceFromUserLocation' which is needed in a label.

Obviously to calculate that it needs to know your current location so in the model object i calculate the current location and set the newLocation value from didUpdateToLocation to my currentLocation property so that the distanceFromLocation can use it to do its calculation. The problem I am getting is that newLocation has a value but as soon as I set currentLocation to it's value it loses the value!